# Synax Error - Unexpected Token for Sortable Grid View

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

I am new to RN, and I am trying to create a sortable grid using the SortableGridView component from react-native-sortable-gridview library.  However, I am getting an error saying "Unexpected token (19:00), which is where the line "

The tutorial I am following does not mention that we need some sort of constructor, method or property, which I found interesting. I believe I have the commas and semicolons in their proper place.

```
import {
  Button,
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  List,
  ListItem,
  ImageBackground
} from "react-native";

import SortableGridView from "react-native-sortable-gridview";

class Rankings extends React.Component {

<SortableGridView
  data={[
    { name: "box1", backgroundColor: "#09f", color: "#fff" },
    { name: "box2", backgroundColor: "#f60", color: "#fff" },
    { name: "box3", backgroundColor: "#333", color: "#fff" },
    { name: "box4", backgroundColor: "#rgba(255, 216, 58, 1)", color: "#333" },
    { name: "box5", backgroundColor: "#rgba(0, 222, 144, 1)", color: "#fff" }
  ]}
  onDragStart={() => {
    console.log("Default onDragStart");
  }}
  onDragRelease={data => {
    console.log("Default onDragRelease", data);
  }}
  renderItem={(item, index) => {
    return (
      <View
        uniqueKey={item.name} // Important! Should add this props!!!
        onTap={() => {
          Alert.alert(`On Tap ${item.name}!`);
        }}
        style={[styles.item, { backgroundColor: item.backgroundColor }]}
      >
        <Text style={[styles.text, { color: item.color }]}>{item.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }}
/>
};
export default Rankings;

I expect a sortable grid to appear with 5 boxes in it. Instead, I get "syntax error unexpected token at <SortableViewGrid", which is right below class Rankings.
```

Answer (score 0):

You must change your package.
try to solve your error.
must install

```
npm i react-native-sortable-grid
```

Now use their multi-props as your requirement and solve your any issues.
[https://github.com/ollija/react-native-sortable-grid][1]